# Displaying number of tests which failed with a certain tag ( Ruby, Cucumber, in Jenkins)

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber

I'm considering adding @high_priority and @low_priority to certain tests in our test suite in order to find out how many high priority (risk) tests have failed. Ideally I'd like a column in Jenkins next to the test job which displays

> 1/100 high priority and 8/60 low priority tests failed.

Though I'm happy with a similar output in the console output if necessary.

Currently Jenkins jobs are running a command line execution like:

```
cucumber --tags @AU_smoke ENVIRONMENT=beta --format html --out 'C:\git\testingworkspace\Reports\smoke_BETA_test_report.html'  --format pretty
```

Edit:
Adding extra jobs isn't really a solution, we have a large amount of jobs which run subsets of all of the tests, so adding extra jobs for high and low priority would require tripling the number of jobs we have.

Comment: May be create two jobs(for high priority tests and for low priority tests)? You can run first high and after low. If high filed, low tests doesn't run.

Comment: The problem is we have lots of different configurations, this would require doubling the number of configurations we have.

Comment: After testing you can execute bash(batch)-script, where will parse result tests-files and after parsing -  print result. This script you can run on post-action section.

Comment: You should be able to create a custom formatter to capture/display this information.

Comment: plsgogame, looks like I'm probably going to have to do that. 
Justin, how do I go about that? If it's complex, do you know of any tutorials?

Comment: I have not used it myself but read about a formatter called: tag_cloud which might be what you want, I would look into it at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've settled on using the description setter plugin with the extra columns plugin. This allows me to add the build description as a column on my views and in my code I have

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.status.to_s=="passed"
    $passed=$passed+1
  elsif scenario.status.to_s=="failed"
    $failed=$failed+1
    puts "FAILED!"
  elsif scenario.status.to_s=="undefined"
    $undefined=$undefined+1
  end
  $scenario_count=$scenario_count+1
  if scenario.failed?
    Dir::mkdir('screenshots') if not File.directory?('screenshots')
    screenshot = "./screenshots/FAILED_#{scenario.name.gsub(' ','_').gsub(/[^0-9A-    Za-z_]/, '')}.png"
    @browser.driver.save_screenshot(screenshot)
    puts "Screenshot created: #{screenshot}"
    embed screenshot, 'image/png'
    #@browser.close
  end
  #@browser.close
end

at_exit do
  end_time=Time.now

  elapsed_time=end_time.to_i - $start_time.to_i
  puts "\#description#scenarios total: #{$scenario_count}, passed: #{$passed}, failed:     #{$failed}, known bug fails: #{$known_bug_failures}, undefined: #{$undefined}.#description#"
...
```

Then in the description setter plugin I use the regex

```
/#description#(.+)#description#/
```

and use the first match group as the build description name. This also allows me to look at a job's build history and see at a glance how many tests there were and how many passed over the previous few weeks.